# Create another entry point page in Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have one question. In zend framework index.php in public folder is an entry point to start. How i can make another .php page say mydata.php in public folder that would work same as index.php but with little customized code?

For example when index.php loads every time it will load index controller and index action but when mydata.php is requested it should load, for example, data(any name) controller and index action of that controller.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Ashish Joshi

Answer (score 0):

You should have an htaccess file setup that redirects all requests to the front controller usually in public/index.php. So, with this setup you won't be able to access mydata.php, but if you create a mydata controller, you should be able to access it like: example.com/mydata